# Timeout - host FTP to VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

For testing purposes I installed virtualbox to simulate a linux(64 bit ubuntu) server.

I configured my network settings like this:
Adapter 1:
NAT
Adapter 2:
Host-only

with my etc/network/interfaces configured like this:

```
#loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#the host-only network interface
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

While my host is operating on 192.168.1.23 with standardgateway 192.168.1.1.

I am able to ping from my host to this virtualbox (192.168.1.23>192.168.56.101) and vice versa, reach the website, database running on the virtualbox etc.

But now I installed an FTP with

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

following this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-vsftpd-ftp-service-server/

Also configured this ftp-server (according to above link)

But whenever I try to reach this virtualbox using FTP I AM able to connect, and I get the folderlist (at least I see '257 /home/user' in filezilla) but after 10 seconds I get the error:

```
- Lost connection
- Unable to retrieve folderlist
```

How to resolve this issue?

(I do not want to use the network-bridge-adapter..)

Comment: I don't see any reason why your setup should not work... maybe some kind of firewall involved or something related to FTPs active/passive mode?

Comment: You are right, it was the firewall of the linux(guest). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The firewall 'libwww-perl' on the linux (guest) virtualbox was blocking the connection somehow!

To disable the firewall I used

```
sudo nano /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

and changed

```
TESTING='0'
```

to

```
TESTING='1'
```

I'm sure you can make an exception on this firewall but I dont really need it since I only use this virtualserver local.